# Website only shows html instead of any css or styling

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I am using react as the client side and node.js as the server side, and using webpack to transpile. When I start the website on local host it is missing all of its styling and css. Any Ideas? This is my frontend webpack that handles the transpiling of my frontend code

```
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
  target: 'node',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  entry: './frontend/src/App',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'backend/build'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
    libraryExport: 'default'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react']
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
      
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react']
          }
        }
      },
      
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [ 'css-loader'],
        sideEffects: true
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

This is my backend/server.js that handles server rendering

```
const express = require('express');
const React = require('react');
const { renderToString } = require('react-dom/server');
const App = require('../backend/build/bundle');
const { matchPath } = require('react-router-dom');

const app = express();

// This is the middleware that will handle all routes
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  // We create a context object that will be passed to the StaticRouter
  const context = {};

  // Render the app component to a string
  const html = renderToString(
    React.createElement(App, {
      location: req.url,
      context,
    })
  );

  // If the app component set a context.url value, it means the user
  // tried to access a protected route that they are not authenticated for.
  // In this case, we redirect them to the login page.
  if (context.url) {
    res.redirect(context.url);
  } else {
    // Send the rendered HTML as the response
    res.send(`
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
        <head>
          <title>My App</title>
        </head>
        <body>
          <div id="root">${html}</div>
          <script src="/build/bundle.js"></script>
        </body>
      </html>
    `);
  }
});


app.listen(3000, () =\> {
console.log('Server is listening on port 3000');
});
```

This is my frontend App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { StaticRouter } from "react-router-dom/server";
import { Footer, Contact, WhoChawewo, Header } from "./containers";
import { Navbar, Background } from "./components";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";

const App = (props) => {
  return (
    <StaticRouter location={props.location} context={props.context}>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Header />} />
        <Route path="/about" element={<WhoChawewo />} />
        <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
      </Routes>
      <Footer />
    </StaticRouter>
  );
};

export default App;
```

And this is my index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
ReactDom.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  )
```

I have tried to add the styling-loader to the webpack config for the frontend but I end up getting an error where the document is not defined. The routing works fine, just no css or images, just basic html is being rendered`

Comment: First try to do some separation of concerne put your frontend file/project on the front and backend for the server,  where is your css file ? and why do you import React on the backend server js ?

Comment: You haven't set up any static asset handling in order to serve `/build/bundle.js`

Comment: It's a bit complicated to help you with so much information, go to your browser and in the network tab look for which CSS file you are calling and if your webpack bundler is generating that CSS file in your build. If you are generating it independently in your HTML file, you must also call it.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your HTML; you are not calling the CSS you want to load. Check which CSS file your webpack generates for you, and then add this to your HTML.

*Note that in this HTML example, I add the link tag*

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
        <head>
          <title>My App</title>
          <link href="/bundle/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
        </head>
        <body>
          <div id="root">${html}</div>
          <script src="/build/bundle.js"></script>
        </body>
      </html>
```

**2nd:** You must send the JS and CSS files for your HTML when you request it to your express server.

```
const path = require("path");
const express = require('express');
const React = require('react');
const { renderToString } = require('react-dom/server');
const App = require('../backend/build/bundle');
const { matchPath } = require('react-router-dom');

const app = express();


app.use('/build', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "dist", "bundle")))


// This is the middleware that will handle all routes
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  // We create a context object that will be passed to the StaticRouter
  const context = {};

  // Render the app component to a string
  const html = renderToString(
    React.createElement(App, {
      location: req.url,
      context,
    })
  );

  // If the app component set a context.url value, it means the user
  // tried to access a protected route that they are not authenticated for.
  // In this case, we redirect them to the login page.
  if (context.url) {
    res.redirect(context.url);
  } else {
    // Send the rendered HTML as the response
    res.send(`
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
        <head>
          <title>My App</title>
          <link href="/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
        </head>
        <body>
          <div id="root">${html}</div>

          <script src="/build/bundle.js"></script>
        </body>
      </html>
    `);
  }
});


app.listen(3000, () => {
console.log('Server is listening on port 3000');
});
```

Note:

Look at: **app.use('/build', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "dist", "bundle")))**

Organize the folder to point to the actual build folder remember, this is an example

Comment: If you still have doubts, let me know, and I'll send you a repository that we have for the interviews where you can download a basic repository that has hot reload and render for react

Comment: Yes I've tried this and it partly worked, my CSS is now there but there are missing fonts and text-coloring. Thanks for the help!